# PHP Shoutcast Stats V2 XML

Tags: php, xml, shoutcast

I have been searching for hours on google on ways to get the data from the

> /stats?sid=1

File on V2 Shoutcast servers.

I am not the Administrator of the server, more like a fan trying to pull information - therefore I cannot access the admin XML file.

I need to pull information such as title, listeners and genre.

I've tried various functions using PHP file_get_contents, CURL and SimpleXML functions

Any help would be appreciated with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "http://ip:port/stats?sid=1";
$nice_url = urlencode($url);
$sc_stats = simplexml_load_file($nice_url);

echo $sc_stats->SERVERTITLE;
echo $sc_stats->BITRATE;
echo $sc_stats->SONGTITLE;
```

etc.